# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Windows 8 Guest macvtap setup

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have little experience with Ubuntu and new to KVM.  I have successfully installed KVM and used virt-manager to add the first guest. I have 4 Ethernet ports on my server. For host server access and management, eth0 is the only interface configured in /etc/network/interfaces. I want to use the other 3 as dedicated for 3 VM guest machines. When I select Advanced Options during configuring a new machine, the Virtual Network 'default': NAT and Specify shared device name are the only 2 selectable options, but I can see Host device eth0 (Not bridged) Host device eth1 (Not bridged), same for eth2 and eth3, then Host device macvtap0 (Not bridged). I select 'default' NAT. After guest is added, I can open Details/NIC and select Host device eth1: macvtap, then login to quest and assign a static IP in network settings. But I cannot ping one guest from the other, or even ping the gateway.
I have been researching this issue for a couple of weeks, so hopefully someone can clear the fog for me and help me move forward.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a bridge with every network device you want to be available to the guest so it can be used by kvm.
More info here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KvmWithBridge and here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking